# Как правильно удалить лишние пробелы в строке?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Как правильно удалить лишние пробелы в строке?
* - это пробел.

```
$text = '**Bla***bla**bla*blabla**bla*
**blabla***bla
*blabla';
echo preg_replace('/[^\S\r\n]+/', ' ', $text);
```

Вот результат:

```
*Bla*bla*bla*blabla*bla*
*blabla*bla
*blabla
```

Проблема в том что не могу удалят пробелы пере новый строкой типа такой. Как задать правило чтобы не оставлять пробел перед новый строкой?

```
Bla*bla*bla*blabla*bla*
blabla*bla
blabla
```

Comment: Как вариант еще https://regex101.com/r/2pzUHh/1 (чистое удаление, замена на пустоту)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Чтобы удалить все пробелы в началах и концах строк, а также заменить множественные подряд стоящие пробелы на единичные, можно воспользоваться одним из следующих вариантов:

1. Если речь только о пробелах, то надо заменять `/^ +| +$|( ) +/m` на `$1`.

   Обращаю внимание, что важен порядок проверок:
   http://ideone.com/M8wuSg - верно
   http://ideone.com/xBA5LS - неверно
2. Если нужны любые побельные символы - то лучше сделать в 2 замены - первая - как у тебя, а вторая `/^(?![\r\n]\s)+|(?![\r\n]\s)+$/m` на пустую строку.

Comment: @KYRAN, ага, взяли только пробелы, без всякой табуляции, как в моем ответе.

Comment: @KYRAN, я уже баг нашёл - множественные пробелы в конце строки обрабатывались неверно. Исправил. Тебе тоже надо поправить.

Comment: @Qwertiy, в конце строки автор пробелы не удаляет.

Comment: @Visman, значит я (как всегда) невнимательно читаю вопрос... Потому что я думал, что именно их и надо удалить.

Comment: @Visman, на всякий случай уточнил в ответе, что именно я делаю.

Comment: @Qwertiy, все равно я дал раньше правильный ответ. А у вас регулярка не правильная :Р

Comment: @Visman, чёрт))) На ideone правильная, а тут я криво поправил. Исправил.

Comment: @KYRAN, исправил косяк, которого на ideone не было, а в ответе был.

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php
$text = '**Bla***bla**bla*blabla**bla*
**blabla';
echo preg_replace('/^([*]+)|([*]){2,}/m', '$2', $text);
```

Для удаления пробелов замените звездочки на знак пробела в регулярном выражении.

Тест http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5de175fc06b16d77ddad968365bafe91c5c8d1bf

Comment: Есть подвох - может быть там была табуляция - его код заменит её на пробел, а твой - оставит.

Comment: Спасибо работает! Но не могу заменить * на пробелов и удаляет `\n` посмотрите пожалуйста :) http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/734e1f3245dbc5f520e0b8e268e0a6409627dc45

Comment: @KYRAN, если я написал `знак пробела`, то это и значит что знак пробела надо поставить, а не класс `\s`.

Comment: @Qwertiy, под пробелом я понимаю пробелы, а не табуляции.

Comment: @Visman, но в вопросе-то все побельные символы кроме переводов строк: `[^\S\r\n]+`.

Comment: @Qwertiy, пусть автор вопроса прямо напишет в вопросе из чего состоят его 'пробелы', потому что сейчас они состоят из звездочек.

Answer (score 0):

Регулярные выражения это здорово, но в данном случае это избыточно. Если вам необходимо в строке заменить какой либо символ на другой или убрать, без всяких условий. Используйте `$ourString = str_replace(' ','',$ourString);` эта функция работает быстрее чем функции работы с регулярными выражениями. Понятно,что на простеньком одноразовом скрипте это, чаще всего, не играет роли, но тем не менее не надо микроскопом гвозди забивать.

Comment: А теперь покажите решении через str_replace() для данной задачи, а не пустую демагогию в ответе.

Comment: только этот код удалит все пробелы, даже одиночные. а задача - оставить одинарные пробелы между не пробелами

Comment: $str = str_replace('  ',' ',$str); $str = str_replace(" \n","\n",$str);  Будет быстрее чем ваша одна строка . заменяем два пробела на один, заменяем пробел и перенос на перенос

Comment: Ага, а потом еще перенос и пробел на перенос. итого 3 вызова функции. (ну или один но с массивами) итого 3 прохода строки. боюсь это уже не особо у регулярки выиграет